# Como criar um evento CellValueChanged no GridView ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview

Tenho um GRID dinâmico, que após o carregamento possibilita o usuário de modifica-lo, trocando os valores das colunas arrastando os objetos (DIV) entre elas. No WinForms, o DataGridView tem um evento chamado CellValueChanged, porém no ASP.NET para o gridView não existe um evento parecido. Alguem sabe alguma solução?